# How to convert JSON data into STRUCTURED data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-schema, snowflake-connector

[image: SAMPLE OUTPUT]        **There are 2 columns post ingestion to snowflake, I want to make the 2nd column inserted below to structural and relational data.**

Now below the point 1 and point 2 are two different columns data, that I want into structural data to be derived from this JSON data below. Can anyone help with required function/procedure in Snowflake

```
  1.  **First Column Data**: {
      "Create-time": 1654252931867,
      "offset": 0,
      "partition": 0,
      "topic": "get-text_MSG"
    }
    
    
   2. **Second Column Data**:
    {
      "parser-output": [
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "product",
          "product_id": "B7CY2YG"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "product",
          "author_name": "Chef Store"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "product",
          "images_chunk": "https://m.media-myntra.com/I/31d_AC_US500_.jpg",
          "images_chunk_popup": "https://m.media-myntra.com/I/719U_AC_SL1500_.jpg",
          "images_chunk_popup_large": "https://m.media-myntra.com/I/31d4-P1gSkL._AC_.jpg",
          "manufacturer_text": "so you comm rest assure that your stove will be protected from all the outdoor elements. |#Fitment DB-60D",
          "no_of_images": 1,
          "no_of_images_popup": "1",
          "no_of_images_popup_large": "1",
          "no_of_user_manual": "n/a",
          "no_of_videos": "0",
          "product_image": "https://m.media-myntra.com/images/I/719Un2I2VjL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
          "user_manual_chunk": "n/a",
          "videos_links": ""
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "product",
          "installation_features": "n/a",
          "installation_price": "n/a",
          "lead_time": "n/a",
          "seller_name": "",
          "shipping_message": "FREE delivery: n/a"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "product",
          "delivery_lead-time": "n/a",
          "frequently_asked_question": "Customer Questions & Answers",
          "image_alt_text": "comp Chef PC46 Cover for DB60D &amp; SGP60B Cookers",
          "item_condition_price": "n/a",
          "long_description": "Its secured to the stove by a set of bungee cords and hooks. This durable cover comes in a khaki tan color which will look great on the patio or at the base comm. Features -Weather-resistant liner. -Bungee cords and hooks for wind protection. -Durable construction for patio or base comm. Specification 46\"x16\"x14\". Weight: 2 lbs.#||#",
          "long_features": "DB-60D",
          "manufacturer_content": "Yes",
          "mp": "PC46",
          "no_of_customer_reviews_greater_21": "No",
          "preferred_product_barge": "No",
          "schema_org_availability": "No",
          "star_1": 1.05,
          "star_2": 1.65,
          "star_3": 1.05,
          "star_4": 2.55,
          "star_5": 8.85,
          "three_sixty_spin": "",
          "total_customer_ratings": "15"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "product",
          "average_rating": "4.1",
          "best_seller_ranking": "160115",
          "brand": "comp Chef",
          "buy-box_winner_name": "n/a",
          "category_path": "Patio, Lawn & Garden#||#Barbecue Grills & Outdoor Cooking#||#Barbecue & Smoker Accessories#||#Barbecue Covers",
          "features": "comp Chef cover #||# Protects your stove from the elements; the covers are secured to the stove by a set of bungee cords and hooks #||# Made with weather resistant material #||# Fits models DB-60, SPG-60P, PRC-60P #||# Measures 46-inches in length by 16-inches in height by 14-inches in width",
          "image_URL_large": "https://m.media-mantra.com/I/719UAC_SL1500_.jpg",
          "image_URL_small": "https://m.media-mantra.com/I/719UAC_SL1500_.jpg",
          "page_title": "comm Chef PC46 Cover for DB60D & SGP60B Cookers : mantra.com: Patio, Lawn & Garden",
          "product_description": "The comp Chef PC46. Protect your outdoor cooker. Durable construction. Fits models DB-60 and SPG-60",
          "product_image": "https://m.media-myntra.com/images/I/719Un2I2VjL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
          "product_name": "comp Chef PC46 Cover for DB60D & SGP60B Cookers",
          "stock_status": "Currently unavailable",
          "user_manual": "N"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "product",
          "stock_message": "Currently unavailable.",
          "stock_status_flag": "0"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "product",
          "URL": "https://www.myntra.com/commp-Chef-PC46-SGP60B-Cookers/dp/B0007CY2YG"
        },
        {
          "OV": "NV",
          "MG": "meta",
          "char-set": "utf-8"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "meta",
          "x-dens-pref etch-control": "on"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "meta",
          "content-type": "text/HTML; char-set=iso-8859-1"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "meta",
          "robots": "NO-INDEX"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "meta",
          "description": "comp Chef PC46 Cover for DB60D & SGP60B Cookers : myntra.com: Patio, Lawn & Garden"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "meta",
          "title": "comp Chef PC46 Cover for DB60D & SGP60B Cookers : mantra.com: Patio, Lawn & Garden"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "meta",
          "title": "comp Chef PC46 Cover for DB60D & SGP60B Cookers : mantra.com: Patio, Lawn & Garden"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "meta",
          "communication": "https://www.mantra.com/commp-Chef-PC46-SGP60B-Cookers/dp/B0007CY2YG"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "TD"
        },
        {
          "OB": "NV",
          "MG": "product",
          "time_to_parse": "1322 ms"
        }
      ],
      "URL-metadata": {
        "batch": "2022",
        "category": "[{\"MG\": \"product\", \"product_id\": \"B0007CY2YG\", \"OB\": \"NV\"}]",
        "child-flag": false,
        "Mg-relation": false,
        "domain": "mantra_com",
        "encoding": "UTF-8",
        "environment": "Prod-THE",
        "fetching-texture": true,
        "gateway-type": "CLIENTELE",
        "info": {
          "current-time": 1650698639108,
          "duration": 354,
          "envy": "Prod-THUD",
          "page-type": [
            "product_page",
            "variation_page"
          ],
          "proxy": "gamut_proxy",
          "URL": "https://www.myntra.com/dp/B0007CY2YG/?m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB"
        },
        "job-id": 1649735439979,
        "job-size": 0,
        "last-get-text-time": 1650698635,
        "page-depth": [
          "product_page",
          "variation_page"
        ],
        "parenthetical-catalogued": "https://www.myntra.com/dp/B0007CY2YG/?m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB",
        "product-info": false,
        "project": "The Home Depot command - Competitive Intelligence",
        "project Id": "P39260633533984451",
        "machine": "XX.XX.XX.XXX:8800",
        "region": "Canada",
        "request-metadata": {
          "allow-redirect": true,
          "cookies": {
            "i18n-prefs": "com",
            "session-id": "146-0873333-2440418",
            "session-id-time": "2082787201l"
          },
          "header-parameters": {
            "Accept": "text/HTML,complication/HTML+XML,application/XML;q=0.9,image/avid,image/web,image/pang,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
            "Accept-Encoding": "grip, deflate, Br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Host": "WWW.mantra.com",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOSarmv7l 8172.62.0) Hepplewhite/537.36 (HTML,like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36"
          },
          "verify": false,
          "web-method": "get"
        },
        "retailer": "mantra_com",
        "retry-count": 1,
        "row-key": "5b9b34b4e652e3f65dcomc1412e68ed17-1649735439979",
        "scripts": [
          "mantra_com_product_page"
        ],
        "persiflage": true,
        "start-time": 1650718263000,
        "sub-batch": "April",
        "sub-project": "Competitive Intelligence",
        "total-input": "[{\"\",\"Sid_SUB_CLASS_NOR\":\"n/a\",\"Sid_rival_presence_order\":\"n/a\",\"id\":\"n/a\"}]",
        "type": "product_page",
        "unique-identifier": "35644",
        "unique-Eyebrow": "1649735439979_1642922463000",
        "unique-Interscholastic": 1650698635,
        "URL": "https://www.myntra.com/dp/B0007CY2YG/?m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB",
        "validate-Parsed-output": false,
        "validation_check": {},
        "vendor": "default",
        "volatility": 0
      }
    }
```

Please don't give the JAVA or PYTHON code for the above problem. As its much possible in SNOWFLAKE. Because as its very hard to manage the coding in other language other than in the SNOWFLAKE SQL as it would be very easy later in case of any structural changes in the data flow pipeline

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the output that you want in more detail.  Parsing JSON is pretty simple in Snowflake, but you have not provided any requirements.

Comment: added the image of desired output format.

Comment: This question is next to impossible to understand, for example, your "expected output" has columns like `zipDetails*`, but that string is not present in your inputs. If you want to get a good answer, please work on the question. E.g. make the inputs much smaller, and provide the exact output you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Once I get the solution would definitely update.

Comment: You won't get a solution until you provide the information that Marcin is referring to.